# How to update the file size on desk while python file writing program runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-writing

I have a python program that performs a socket connection, get some data and writes them to a file. The data is quite large. I need to make sure that the writing is in a good progress while the program is running by clicking of the file properties to see the size increases as the program runs for more time.

To simplify, the main logic of the issue appears in this simple example:

```
myfile = open ("test.txt","w")
x = 0
while x < 1000000:
    myfile.write("line:"+str(x))
    print("line",str(x))
    x+=1
```

This program writes 1 million line. During the writing, I check the file size and it is always 0 KB. Only when the program finishes, I can see the file size. This is inconvenient for me.

1) What is the reason for that? I recall that I had run programs but I was able to see file size progress while the program runs?
I am not sure if it was python program but I used to do this usually to monitor progress.

2) How can I reflect the file writing progress so when I click on the file properties while the python program runs, I can see the file size increases.

**UPDATE:**
Unfortunately none of the solutions seem to be practical. First, I do fresh writing with "w" in purpose. The program should write new fresh data every run. I do not want to append. Second, the program should write the data at onece in the loop. At the end, I should close the file (which I missed).
What I need is something like synchronization or flushing. I do not thing it is practical to close the file for a loop that take 100 thousands iterations.

Comment: Because the writes are buffered. Does running the script as `python -u script.py` help?

Comment: @user9371654, as far as I am seeing you are calling `write` which overwrites the content of the file.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yes. If  I want to append I add a second argument when opening the file with "a" argument. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @user9371654, suggestions for what specifically?

Comment: @heemayl `python -u script.py` does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should close every file you open, but you can use a context manager to avoid calling close. In addition, you are using the `'w'` mode which will overwrite the contents of your file every time you open it, so you have to change to `'a'` (append mode), in order to see the file increasing in size.

```
x = 0
while x < 1000000:
    with open ("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile = open ("test.txt","a") #opens file to append
        myfile.write("line:"+str(x)) # appends to file
    print("line", x) # no need to call str
    x += 1
```

Comment: Nice solution. Which one is faster among ours ?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I want to write fresh data every run. So the "w" is in purpose. I want to see the increase in the same run. In that same write (I do very long run that takes long hours).

Comment: @Agile_Eagle, it seems my solution is a bit faster. I use %time in jupyter to see yours and mine, and mine takes: 7.15 µs while yours 10us.

Comment: @user9371654, the problem if you write it write it every time is that in the end just the last iteration will count, and you will barely notice an increase in the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This will take more time but will achieve your goal. The important part is closing the file each time.

```
x = 0
while x < 1000000:
    myfile = open ("test.txt","a") #opens file to append
    myfile.write("line:"+str(x)) # appends to file
    myfile.close() # closes file(this will update the file size each time)
    print("line",str(x))
    x+=1
```

Comment: I don't understand why you got downvoted, and I think your answer is correct, so +1 (from my side).

Comment: @Agile_Eagle I do not think it is practical to close the file for a run that may take 10 hours. I am writing continuously in a single run. Yes I should close the file but at the end of the run. I do "w" in purpose. I need fresh data every run.

Comment: @user9371654 ok your wish. I didn't know that when I wrote the question

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the file every time you add new data.

Comment: But you also need to open it to append. If you open it to write the initial data will be erased

Comment: yes.. that's normal, no need to write it explicitly only if you are talking to dumb people

Comment: but you can't assume the OP knows that